# CTRL+G not workiing:: cannot include image using that shortcut in markup here

Tags: markup

when inserting image your markup help suggests using CTRL+G.

Nothing happens with CTRL+g but if I use CTRL+G  (caps) then Microsoft edge starts talking to me, reading from the top of you web page down.  I went to Microsoft's community forum and and was told basically that is how CTRL+G works but was unable get an answer on how to turn that off or to rename the key to something else.  I don't like edge but I do use it when I need active-x for forums as I keep chrome locked down tight.  Is there a way to stop this?  I usually get good answers a Microsoft but "that is how it works" was not expected.

Comment: Which tool are you talking about? "Markup" doesn't have any keyboard shortcus.

Comment: Sorry - the problem occurred when inserting an IMAGE not CODE, I am not an expert here so I RTFM and clicked on advanced  help and saw the message "You can also press CTRL + G to insert an image.  I usually think or keyboard special keys like CTRL or ALT as being shortcuts.

Comment: Questions about SO itself belong on [meta]. This site is for programming related questions. SO is also not responsible for the keyboard shortcuts that MS decided to use in Edge.

Comment: Also, Edge lists `Ctrl+Shift+G` as the shortcut for *Read aloud*, not Ctrl+G.